# How to active an Hibernate loader for custom loading?

Tags: hibernate

I have an unnormalized table like

```
 __________________________________
| id | id_parent | id_child | flag |
| 1  |     1     |    7     |   1  |
| 2  |     1     |    8     |   1  |
| 3  |     2     |    7     |   0  |
 __________________________________
```

And I want to map to somethink like

```
    ________        _______
   | Parent | -->* | Child |
    ________        _______
```

With a trivial mapping I get childs repetead as I expected (although I get 6 childs for the parent with id = 1 when I expected 4).

```
<class name="com.example.Parent" table="unnormalized_table">

  <id name="id" column="ID_PARENT" type="long" access="field" />

  <bag name="childs" lazy="false" mutable="false" fetch="join" access="field" where="FLAG = 1">
    <key column="ID_PARENT" />
    <one-to-many class="com.example.Child"/>
  </bag>
    
</class>
```

Instead, with a [loader](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querysql-load):

```
<class name="com.example.Parent">

  <id name="id" column="ID_PARENT" type="long" access="field" />

  <bag name="childs" lazy="false" mutable="false" fetch="join" access="field" where="FLAG = 1">
    <key column="ID_PARENT" />
    <one-to-many class="com.example.Child"/>
  </bag>

  <loader query-ref="retrieveParent" />

</class>

<sql-query name="retrieveParent">
    <return alias="p" class="com.example.Parent" />
    select ? as {p.id} from dual
</sql-query>
```

But with this mapping Hibernate execute this query:

```
select ... from Parent this_ 
left outer join unnormalized_table u_ 
            on this_.ID_PARENT=u_.ID_PARENT 
            and (
                u_.FLAG = 1
            )  
where
        this_.ID_PARENT=?
```

Obviously the query fails because doesn't find the table Parent.
**The problem is that the loader is not being executed.**

In [this](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.ar/2012/01/creating-custom-entity-loaders.html) post says that Hibernate logs some stuff:

> DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.NamedSQLQuerySecondPass  - Named SQL query:
>
> DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl  - Checking named SQL query
>
> DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery  - starting
> processing of sql query
>
> DEBUG
> org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor  - map ping
> alias [sh] to entity-suffix [0_]

But I only gets the first kind of log.
I'm missing some hibernate configuration to active the loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the mapping posted in the question doesn't work at first but there is no configuration needed for the get the loader working, just use Session#get or Session#load, a query won't work obviously.

But if we want to achive the lazy=false + fetch=join we must do explicitly, otherwise hibernate will execute the custom query first and then resolve the join.

This mapping do the work.

```
<class name="com.example.Parent">

    <id name="id" column="ID_PARENT" type="long" access="field" />

     <!-- lazy and fetch attributes doesn't matter because we must do the fetch join explicitly -->
     <!-- same for the where clause -->
     <!-- I don't know if the mutable attribute is used by hibernate in this case -->
     <bag name="childs" lazy="false" mutable="false" fetch="join" access="field" where="FLAG = 1">
        <key column="ID_PARENT" />
        <one-to-many class="com.example.Child"/>
      </bag>

    <loader query-ref="retrieveParent" />
</class>
<sql-query name="retrieveParent">
  <return alias="p" class="com.example.Parent" />
  <return-join alias="childs" property="p.childs"/>
  <![CDATA[select :parentId as {p.id},{childs.*} from dual left join (select * from unnormalized_table where flag = 1) childs on :parentId = childs.id_parent]]> 
</sql-query>
```